# Installing ocp-build with opam failing

Tags: linux, ocaml, ocp-build

I'm trying to install the Ocaml ide Ocaml-top in a linux virtual machine (vmware). When I get to one of its dependences, ocp-build, I get the following error:

```
The compilation of ocp-build failed at "make".

opam version 1.2.2
os linux
command make
compiler system (4.02.3)
exit code 2
[...]
Makefile:277: recipe for target 'libs/ocplib/ocamllexer.ml' failed

Makefile:160: recipe for target 'boot/ocp-build.asm' failed
make[1]: ocamllex.opt: Command not found
make[1]: ***[libs/ocplib-lang/ocamllexer.ml] Error 127
make: *** [boot/ocp-build.asm] Error 2

How to I fix this and get Ocaml-Top installed?
```

Comment: perhaps try `opam update` and then try it again?

Comment: Your compiler lacks ocamllex.opt.  I guess it is a system switch. Reinstall ocaml not forgetting make opt.opt